# Custom logo and button not appear in UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I Have UINavigarionController and I want to add custom background and logo and left button to the navigation bar I could add background but my logo and button not appear, would you please help me , Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked and i am getting the logo and button but with one change

```
  UIButton *button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  //[button addTarget:self action:@selector(parametres:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25)];

 UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;

UIImageView *navigationImage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 30)];
navigationImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu.png"];
UIImageView *workaroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 30)];
[workaroundImageView addSubview:navigationImage];

self.navigationItem.titleView= workaroundImageView;
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu.png"]];
```

Just specify the image type i.e not menu as menu.png and just add it for your navigationItem by setting UINavigationControllerDelegate to you class as above good luck and please share your results

Comment: it's not worked, I create them in app delegate not in UIViewController class

Comment: why do want to create in AppDeleagte usually all such task must be done in the viewWillAppear method of your viewcontroller

Comment: since I want to have the same structure in my all navigation controller not copy and paste all code in all my view

Comment: to my knowledge tats not possible you can have this code in a rootViewController as Shaggy said

Answer (score 0):

**barButton can't be set to be used in whole app.**

Each `ViewController` provides own `barButtonItems` and `titleView` to the `navigationItem` so you have to move the code of setting logo and button to the rootViewController class

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create in your AppDelegate

Open your ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
    self.navigationItem.title=@"Title"; //Set the title
    [self CustomButton];
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

-(void) CustomButton
{
    UIButton *but=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];//create a button
    but.frame=CGRectMake(290, 4, 40, 40);// set the button frame size
    [but setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [but addTarget:self action:@selector(call here) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:but];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btn;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;

}
```

Hope its useful for you:)